# grep strings in list with r

Tags: r, excel, list

There is a list of 6700 elements for spreadsheet names of excel files. I am interested in "Alpha_Beta", but there are similar names like "Alpha_Beta calc", "Alpha_Beta input", "Alpha-Beta", "Alpha Calc",..

`grep("Alpha_Beta", list)` gave me more than just "Alpha_Beta", the outcome included "Alpha_Beta input", for example.

I ended up with a two-step solution.

```
z <- grep("\\<Alpha\\>", list_sheet_names, value = T)

y <- grep("Alpha_Beta", z, value =  T)
```

I wonder if there is a better way.

the outcome of `dput(head(list_sheet_names))`

```
list(list("02Annual", file_names = "2002 reports/Ec2002/annual2002.xls"), 
    list("020102", file_names = "2002 reports/Ec2002/ecem020102.xls"), 
    list("020109", file_names = "2002 reports/Ec2002/ecem020109.xls"), 
    list("020116", file_names = "2002 reports/Ec2002/ecem020116.xls"), 
    list("020123", file_names = "2002 reports/Ec2002/ecem020123.xls"), 
    list("020130", file_names = "2002 reports/Ec2002/ecem020130.xls"))
```

The outcome of one element in the list is:

```
list("report", "Menu", "Title Sheet", "H3_NG_EFS", "AB Input", 
    "Alpha_Beta", "B 375 Rpt", "Iodines", "Gross Data DB", "Release DB", 
    "Gross Iodine (2)", "Print Header", "Get Iodine", "Print Iodines", 
    "Print Alpha & 375", "Print Tritium & Beta", "Print Report", 
    "Clear Inputs", "AEMR DATE Function", "Get Tritium", "Menu Macros", 
    "Notes & Remarks", "Module1", "Module2", file_names = "2002 reports/Ec2002/em020102.xls")
```

Comment: Try `^Alpha_Beta$` or simply use `==` instead of `grep` if it is an exact match. E.g. `list_sheet_names == "Alpha_Beta"`.

Comment: The outcome of `grep("^Aplha_Beta$", list_all_sheet_names, value = T)` is `character(0)`.

Comment: What is `class(list_sheet_names)`?

Comment: It is a `list`.

Comment: Can you add `dput(head(list_sheet_names))` to your question so that we have a sample of what you are working with?

Comment: Thanks for adding the `dput` that is helpful. So where are the sheet names? Are they the first element in your nested list: "02Annual", "020102", etc.? Or are you trying to match the file name?

Comment: The first element contains the sheet names, and I tried to match the sheet names with `Alpha_Beta`.

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: There are over 6700 excel files, I want to narrow down excel files having the `Alpha_Beta` spreadsheet.  I got 758 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over your list and use `==` to create a logical value to test if the sheet names are 'Alpha_Beta'. `which` return the index for the sheets that are 'Alpha_Beta'. If none are found the value will be `integer(0)`:

```r
lapply(list_sheet_names, \(x) which(x[!nzchar(names(x))] == "Alpha_Beta"))
```

**Example**

Based on the data you added to your question this should work:

```r
list_sheet_names <- list(list("report", "Menu", "Title Sheet", "H3_NG_EFS", "AB Input", 
                              "Alpha_Beta", "B 375 Rpt", "Iodines", "Gross Data DB", "Release DB", 
                              "Gross Iodine (2)", "Print Header", "Get Iodine", "Print Iodines", 
                              "Print Alpha & 375", "Print Tritium & Beta", "Print Report", 
                              "Clear Inputs", "AEMR DATE Function", "Get Tritium", "Menu Macros", 
                              "Notes & Remarks", "Module1", "Module2", file_names = "2002 reports/Ec2002/em020102.xls"))

# Answer given above
lapply(list_sheet_names, \(x) which(x[!nzchar(names(x))] == "Alpha_Beta"))
# [[1]]
#   
# 6
```

Comment: This solution gave me 2 outcomes, but I got 758.  The outcome pattern is that the spreadsheet `Alpha_Beta` is the `Sheet 1`, always the first sheet on the left, among many sheets in one element of the list.  `Alpha_Beta` is placed in the middle of multiple sheets in most of files.

Comment: no success.  I provided one element in the list.

Comment: @pinawa, ah I see. The added data helps. This answer assumes all unnamed elements are sheet names (so it excludes the element `file_names`.

Comment: Your solution provided 793 output, more than what my solution did, 758.  I will do a comparison later on.

By the way, how can I keep `file_names` info with the associated `Alpha_Beta`?

Comment: what is `\(x)`?

Comment: `\(x)` is shorthand notation to create an anonymous function that was introduced in R 4.1.0. It's the equivalent to writing `function(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Filter` as follows:

```
 Filter(\(x)x[[1]] == 'Alpha_Beta', list_sheet_names)
```

Comment: This solution also gave me 2 outcomes as well, with the same outcome pattern.

Comment: @pinawa you should consider including the sheet names that are valid and those that are not valid in your example